# Clickable Python CLI Instantiation

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface

I'm trying to make my `.py` script clickable!

**What I Have**

The CLI program I created using Python works. I open Command Prompt and enter `python my_script.py` and everything works as expected. I want to make it clickable so a user doesn't have to run any commands!

**What I've Tried**

I created a `.bat` file in vim that runs the `python my_script.py` command. When I click it, the desired behavior is not achieved. Command Prompt opens for about a millisecond then closes.

**My Question**

How can I create a better `.bat` file so that my CLI program works with the click of a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports being called in a mode where it can ignore the first line of the script with `-x`.  This coupled with a wrapper batch file means you can actually put the entire Python script in a batch file.

This little script shows how this can be done.  It's a self-contained

```
@echo off
rem = """ # This is run in the batch file to launch Python
python -x "%~f0" %*
goto endofPython
rem = """

# Your python code goes here ..

def main():
    print("Hello from Python")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

rem = """ # This section is run after Python is done, here just
          # just run pause to keep the console window open
:endofPython
pause
rem = """
```

Answer (score 1):

Python, for better or worse does not allow you to specify the path to the script, and will not search the path for the script.

The official word, and I hate to say this, is that you must associate the `Python.exe` executable you want to run python scripts with the extension `.py` and then you can double click your `script.py` or type `\path\to\script.py` into the CMD prompt, and it will run the script.

I hate this from a standpoint of not wanting to accidentally execute a script by clicking it, and from the perspective of wanting to have multiple versions of python installed and choosing which one would do the execution.

There is an (IMHO) annoying (Kludgy) work-around.

You can create a File type for each instance of Python, you might have, and then associate it with the `.py`

so you could create the FTypes you need and associate them in a script at the time of to launch the script from the batch file:

```
FTYPE Py23=C:\Path\To\Pthon-23\python.exe %*
FTYPE Py38=C:\Path\To\Pthon-38\python.exe %*
```

Then your script could do this:

```
@Echo off
ASSOC .py=Py38
"C:\Path\To\Script.py"
ASSOC .py=
```